# Backup filename format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

What is ddddddd number in backup file-name when generated with auto backup and how to get manually?

Filename format

```
DB-NAME_backup_YYYY_MM_DD_HHmmss_ddddddd.bak
```

Comment: It's a timestamp, not sure what you mean by 'how to get manually?'

Comment: tnx a lot, i used GETDATE() function instead of SYSDATETIME()

Comment: select CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121)

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer 
    select CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121)